# How to get 4x4 matrix from integrating column vector and its transpose?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

This is from Finite Element Methods. Part of potential energy approach. Can someone show me how to come to this symetric matrix:
$$ [K]=EI/L^3\begin{bmatrix}
12&6L&-12&6L\\
&4L^2&-6L&2L^2\\
& & 12&-6L\\
&&&4L^2
\end{bmatrix} $$
EI - constant

Using this equation:
$$ [K]=EI\int_0^L {[B]^T [B]}dx $$
Given: 
$[B]=  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{12x-6L}{L^3} & \frac{6xL-4L^2}{L^3} & \frac{-12x+6L}{L^3} & \frac{6xL-2L^2}{L^3}\\
    \end{bmatrix}$

I don't understand how I can have a 4x4 matrix when multiplying vector and its transpose gives me a scalar.
Here is what I have so far:
$$[B]^T[B]=\frac{144x^2-144xL+36L}{L^6}+\frac{36x^2L^2-48xL^3+16L^4}{L^6}+\frac{144x^2-144xl+36L}{L^6}+\frac{36x^2L^2-24xL^3+4L^4}{L^6}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{L^6}(288x^2+24x^2L^2-288xL-72xL^3+72xL^3+72L+20L^4)$$

$$ EI\int_0^L {[B]^T [B]}dx =$$
$$=\frac{EI}{L^6}(96x^3+24x^3L^2-144x^2L-36x^2L^3+72xL+20xL^4)_0^L=$$
$$=EI(\frac{-48}{L^3}+\frac{8}{L}+\frac{72}{L^4})$$
And I got scalar. Not a 4x4 matrix.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is written, $[B]$ is a row vector. Then $[B]^T$ is a column vector. So, $[B]^T[B]$ is of the form
$$\pmatrix{b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_n}\pmatrix{b_1&b_2&\dots&b_n}=\pmatrix{{b_1}^2&b_1b_2&\dots\\ \vdots & \ddots \\ b_nb_1&\dots & {b_n}^2}$$

Comment: Oh, what a glorious face palm moment.
Thank you.